Помогите выбрать базу данных для большого анализа данных
Подскажите как решить задачу по поиску, агрегации данных в базах данных.
На достаточно мощном сервере есть база MySQL в ней несколько таблиц с наборами данных.
Количество столбцов, название иногда повторяются, но зачастую разные.
Поиск и сравнение можно сделать по некоторым полям. Как делать SQL запросы я знаю.
Проблема в том, что в каждой таблице содержится до 100 миллионов записей.
Хочу все свести в одну таблицу (из всех) дополняя записи по строке.
Но с таким объёмом MySQL не справляется, очень долго. Посоветуйте базу данных для выполнения данной задачи.

Все SQL примерно одинаковы. Если у вас что-то слишком долго - оптимизируйте запросы, добавляйте индексы, кешируйте. Также стоит добавить конкретики в вопрос, что за запросы (просто JOIN или простынки по 3-4 страницы? Что есть быстро и долго в вашем понимании, приведите цифры. На каком железе, помещается ли вся БД в оперативную память?

Нужно больше информации. Возможно, стоит посмотреть в сторону колоночных (columnar, column-wide) СУБД. В некоторых реляционках есть колоночные индексы, например в Sql Server, в MariaDB.

Ещё я могу порекомендовать легковесную колоночную DuckDB вместо монструозных тяжёлых СУБД.

Обратите внимание на колоночные СУБД, к примеру - Clickhouse, как раз заточены под агрегацию на огромных объемах и скоростях
